# Adaptavist Script Runner (Groovy) - Create subtask on click

Tags: groovy, jira

I´m a bit lost with the Adaptavist Script Runner for JIRA.

I want to create several subtasks via a clickable button within an epic.

I managed to create a subtask via script but I have not managed to find a solution where the user can click on something and then several subtasks are created at once.

Anybody got a good solution for that?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can create transition from any to any status and place groovy script to this transition which will be create subtasks. But also scriptrunner have ability to customize UI [docs](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/5.4.47/confluence/CustomisingUI.html).